# Restore sql Backup file in C#

Tags: c#

How to Restore Backup(.bak) file of Sql in c#.Net

I can take the backup of my database but when I try to restore, it gives me error of  "Database in Use"

Comment: Do we get to see what code you are using or do we have to guess?

Comment: String str = @"RESTORE DATABASE [" + Application.StartupPath + @"\DMSdatabase\DMSdb.mdf] FROM  DISK = N'" + BL.DbBkPath + "' WITH  FILE = 1,KEEP_REPLICATION, NOUNLOAD,REPLACE,STATS = 10";

Comment: this is what i used to Restore the backup

Comment: Hmmm you can check rights as well that if your code has the right on the db file

Answer (score 1):

The database you are restoring is already in the server. You need to add WITH REPLACE with your statement to replace the existing one.  e.g.

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'
WITH REPLACE
GO
```

Comment: i am running the restore query through my application.

Comment: application is currently using database so, it is giving me an error that "Database in Use".