# How to restore SQL Server backups using asp.net and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How to restore SQL Server backup using C#?

```
try
{
    string test = "D:\\backupdb\\05012017_130700.Bak";

    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Restore database EmpolyeeTable from disk='D:\\backupdb\\05012017_130700.Bak'", con);

    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Response.Write("restore database successfully");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("Error During backup database!");
}
```

Comment: Has the user who execute the command privileges on sql?

Comment: Response.Write(ex.ToString()); will tell you whats up.

Comment: More information would be useful. What sort of errors are you getting? What have you tried? Also, the code block is incomplete. What happens before the first line?

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error During backup database!");
        }` Why do I see so many pieces of daft code like this? You suppress the real error and replace it with a useless arbitrary string. What possible purpose is there in doing that? Check what the exception is telling you and report it properly.

Comment: @Alex K has a good point....

Comment: while debug error showing.can you resolve the error.

Comment: "can you resolve the error". No, because you haven't told us what the error is...

Comment: The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login. Possible causes include the following:  the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server; the server was too busy to accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore sql Backup file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474862/restore-sql-backup-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The key points there being "Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work."

Comment: ok so that tells you it's not even connecting to the server properly. have you verified that the server is running, is a supported version and isn't busy? Can you connect to it via SSMS from the same machine where you run the .NET code (and using the same credentials)? Can you edit your code to show us how you are connecting to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Quite weird requerement you have right there. I´ve never heard of someone restoring a database backup from a webpage, and as @Alex K. told, it would be quite rare that the user that uses your web application have the required previleges.

Anyway, supposing that everything told above is OK, the code to restore a backup would be this:

Use this:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Code:

```
        private void TakeBackup()
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Server + ";Initial Catalog=" + Database + ";User Id=" + Username + ";Password=" + Password + ";");
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK' WITH REPLACE GO";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

This is going to work specifically for the problem you posted. Be sure to set all the parameters of your database server on the connection string, it seems from the comments on your question that you are having communication issues. You have to solve that problems before you do anything. Some tips for that:

- Be sure you set all the parameters on connection string the right way
- Try to connect using another tool like ODBC so you can test all parameters
- Check out SQL Network settings to see if TCP/IP is enabled

Comment: where to get the file name

Comment: where do you have the incorrect syntax?. Replace on your query with the correct DB name and backup file

Comment: i have to give back file location know.i gave already.again show the error

Comment: Is it a compilation error?. Is it an exception?. Post details.

Comment: protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString =("Data Source=SYSTEM-6-PC;Initial Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True");
            try
            {  con.Open();
                SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE EmpolyeeTable FROM DISK = 'D:\backupdb.BAK' WITH REPLACE GO";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { throw;
            }
            finally
{con.Dispose();
 con.Close();
            }